# Tramp using ssh does not source .bash_profile / .profile

Tags: bash, emacs, aquamacs, tramp

I'm using Aquamacs (graphical emacs for OSX using emacs 24 and tramp version 2.2.3) to edit some files on a remote server. Tramp is set up to use **ssh** and works fine in terms of editing files.

It fails when it comes to compiling because the compiler is not in the path. It seems like tramp does not source any of the profile files like **.profile** or **.bash_profile**.
/bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash so bash should be the shell used by tramp. A shell started within emacs on the remote server won't source anything, too.
A ssh connection from a regular terminal emulator (tried *Terminal* and *X11* on OS X) works as expected (everything sourced correctly).

Any ideas?

Comment: A related issue at http://emacs.stackexchange.com: [How do I make tramp+eshell use my environment customized in the remote ~/.bash_profile](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7673/5165).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash so bash should be the shell used by
>   tramp.

Its not the same. When invoked as "sh", it will behave like sh and not
bash, hence the bash specific rc/profile files (e.g. ~/.bash_profile,
~/.bashrc) won't be sourced. However ~/.profile will be read. Your
problem might be you are using bash syntax to setup stuff in your
~/.profile.

This will not work:

```
export PATH=/some/path:$PATH
```

But this will:

```
PATH=/some/path:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: In my case .profile is totally ignored. Sourcing it by hand when invoked /bin/sh does in fact result in a correct path but on its own tramp seems not to source ~/.profile.

Comment: I'm not sure whether putting `export PATH` on a separate line in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` would make tramp understand it, but I tried to make `EDITOR` be set by tramp in a similar way, and it didn't work neither in `~/.profile` nor `~/.bash_profile`, so I ended up setting it once again through `tramp-remote-process-environment`, as I told in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7685/5165 , which is not totally convenient because different remote hosts might need different values.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and could see from my shell history that tramp was executing `/bin/sh` as a non-login shell, meaning that `~/.profile` wouldn't be executed.

This sounds like what the emacs manual is saying [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-programs.html):

> Another way to find the remote path is to use the path assigned to the remote user by the remote host. Tramp does not normally retain this remote path after login. However, tramp-own-remote-path preserves the path value, which can be used to update tramp-remote-path.
>
> ```
>       (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
> ```
>
> Note that this works only if your remote /bin/sh shell supports the login argument ‘-l’.

Adding `'tramp-own-remote-path` to `tramp-remote-path` as described added the `-l` flag to the command I saw in my history and sourced `~/.profile`, as expected.

(This is described in [the accepted answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7685) to the question linked in [Ivan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463152/tramp-using-ssh-does-not-source-bash-profile-profile#comment44690209_10463152), but it doesn't mention that the PATH is respected by sourcing `~/.profile`, which means other environment customization can be done in that file.)