# How can I load a server's specific R installation (environment module) when launching a local installation of emacs?

Tags: r, emacs, environment-variables, hpc, ess

I am using a cluster with [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/). This means that I must specifically load any R version other than the default (2.13) so to load R 3.0.1, I have to specify

```
module load R/3.0.1
R
```

I have added `module load R/3.0.1` to `.bashrc`, so that if I ssh into the server and load R, it opens 3.0.1 by default. But when I open R on the server (`M-x R`, starting data directory: `/ssh:myserver`), it loads the default R installation (2.13).

This question is similar to previous questions except that I am accessing R on a server using a local installation of emacs.  ([ESS to call different installations of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906909/ess-to-call-different-installations-of-r) and [How can I specify the R version opened by ESS session in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574738/how-can-i-specify-the-r-version-opened-by-ess-session-in-emacs))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1. Identify path of R module: `module show R/3.0.1`
2. add to your .emacs: `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/path/to/R-3.0.1/bin")`

---

bash called by TRAMP  via ssh does execute its initialization files but which files ultimately get executed depends on several things. You can check if your `~/.bashrc` gets executed at all when you use TRAMP to connect to the server by adding something like `echo "bashrc here"` to the file. Then set variable

```
(setq tramp-verbose 9)
```

and try connecting. Now see if you can spot that message in a buffer called `*debug tramp/ssh...*`.

If you don't have any additional settings, TRAMP calls remote shell as `/bin/sh` (http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-shell-setup) so `bash` will execute `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). You can also see how the shell is called in that `*debug tramp/ssh...*` buffer, the relevant line will be

```
tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell `/bin/sh'...done
```

Try adding the `module load R/3.0.1` to `~/.profile` first. If that does not help, try forcing TRAMP to call `bash` by its proper name by setting

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
```

UPDATE: If all else fails, you can just open shell `M-x shell`, then ssh to you server which should take care of the proper modules initialization (because you mentioned that interactive ssh connection works as expected). Once on the server, launch R and then do `M-x ess-remote` to make ESS aware of existing R session. This way you don't rely on TRAMP at all.

Comment: thanks for the hints, but I still can't see how to get this to work. I have 'module load R/3.0.1' in both my .profile and .bashrc but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Did you try adding the debugging messages to `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and/or `.bashrc` and then checking the `*debug tramp/ssh..*` buffer to see that the files are executed after the connection is established?

Comment: By debugging message, do you mean adding a line like "echo 'bashrc loaded"?

Comment: yes, and similar messages to other files to see which one(s) gets loaded.

Comment: okay. So it is reading my .bashrc, but when I open R, it is ignoring the command `module load R/3.0.1`, although this line works as expected when launching R on the remote machine from the bash shell

Comment: `module` is supposed to modify the environment. If it doesn't work under TRAMP for some reason, you can try adding the path to correct R: `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/path/to/R-3.0.1/bin")`

Comment: I have just added an alternative method to use correct R that uses your working ssh configuration and doesn't rely on TRAMP.

Comment: This answer saved me from having to ask a similar question, thanks!

Comment: By default, TRAMP will not use the PATH constructed by .profile unless you explicitly tell it to do so. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169654/288545) for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When TRAMP runs a shell command on the remote host, it calls `/bin/sh -c`.  There doesn't seem to be a way to tell `sh` to source any files at initialization when it is called like that.  So let's instead configure TRAMP to call `/bin/bash -c`.  Then `bash` will source `BASH_ENV`, which we can point at a custom file that configures the modules.

So, first, configure TRAMP to use `/bin/bash`.  To do this, we need to modify the `tramp-methods` variable.  It's an alist, where the keys are strings denoting the connection type.  I use the `"scpx"` connection type, but you can change that to a whichever connection type you use.

```
(let ((scpx-method (cdr (assoc "scpx" tramp-methods))))
      (add-to-list 'scpx-method '(tramp-remote-shell "/bin/bash"))
      (add-to-list 'tramp-methods (cons "scpx" scpx-method)))
```

Then, we can configure `tramp-remote-process-environment` to point at a file that will contain our module configuration.

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "BASH_ENV=~/.bash_env")
```

Then, open up the `~/.bash_env` file on the remote machine.  You'll need to source the files that set up your module system.  We use a different module system, so I'm not entirely sure what file you'll need, but perhaps you'll find it in `/etc/profile.d`.  Here's what my file contains:

```
source /etc/profile.d/z00_lmod.sh
module -q restore
```

Again, I'm not familiar with your module system, but that second line simply loads up my default set of modules.

Lastly, since the module system configures your `PATH`, we need to get TRAMP to use it.  By default, TRAMP just uses the contents of `tramp-remote-path`.  But if you add `tramp-own-remote-path`, it will pull in the contents of `PATH`.

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```